# Google chrome extension for paging

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I do not like paging present on the websites.

I like to read articles in the single page view.

Are there any google chrome extension which can show the article in single page instead of multi page ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [AutoPager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mmgagnmbebdebebbcleklifnobamjonh) for Chrome.

> AutoPager is a Chrome extension which automatically loads the next page of a site inline when you reach the end of the current page for infinite scrolling of content. By default AutoPager works with a ton of sites, including Lifehacker, the New York Times, Digg, eBay, Amazon, Yahoo, YouTube, flickr, live, msn, myspace, wikipedia, ebay,taobao,Twitter and, of course, Google.